# How to cheaply fix crooked looking tile?

Tags: tile

Is there any way of making the tiles on the back wall look straight?[image]

Comment: Tye tiles are straight the ceiling and wall transition is crooked.

Comment: Can you show pics , five feet away. May be able to dado a board. And slides down on high end . Up on the other. And paint it to match ceiling , so you dont see it . Along window.

Comment: add another row of tile

Comment: Kris - yes, it is the wall that is at an angle as our roof line widens towards the back. Robert - what is a dado a board? Jsotola- another line of tile would be on the ceiling as it is following the roof line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned in a reply above that you're currently out of budget, which makes a "total rework" kind of fix out of scope.

What about some "distraction" type of fix? Get a printed [peel-and-stick wallpaper](https://wallsneedlove.com/pages/featured-wallpaper-collections) with an [irregular pattern](https://wallsneedlove.com/collections/geometric-wp-collection/products/ab-linear-rainbow-removable-wallpaper) that distracts from the asymmetry and will be fine for now (for real, or ironically) until in a few years you can't stand it any more but have the $ for a more substantial fix.

Edit: You could apply this to the part above the tile, but also you could apply this to the tile. Whatever "distracts" more and works well with the pattern you choose...

Answer (score 2):

Trim baby, trim... 
You will need some custom angled molding made to follow the straight lines of the tile joints, but "absorb" the crookedness of the wall in its internal angles. It will not be an easy fix though, it will take a very skilled millworker / cabinetmaker.

Comment: I was thinking trim, the rest of the room around the windows and nooks have a brushed steel trim, do you think it would look weird if the trim was different just in that one place?

Comment: I would not, but I'm a man so my sense of aesthetics is suspect. Just ask my wife...

Answer (score 2):

If you were willing to replace the top course of tiles, you could swap in a mosaic (either regular or irregular), and the skew would be effectively hidden.

Failing that, get the roof/wall skimmed down to a level line.

Comment: That sounds expensive, we are at the end of the build and have a grand total of zero to spend

Comment: Sorry -- neither of those are super cheap. My last idea is to paint that section of wall almost the same color as the tile.

Answer (score 2):

### [Dazzle camouflage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dazzle_camouflage)

Either re-tile, or re-paint, with some sort of irregular pattern that makes it almost impossible to see the uneven lines.

This will require giving the bathroom "character", and many buyers are not great fans of "character", but it is the most expedient way to mask the error.

And it's hardly new in architecture; things like popcorn ceilings or knockdown drywall are designed to hide flaws in drywalling.